# How to get uid from ssh certificate attribute

Tags: ssh, sshd, ssh-keys

I'm working on deployment of ssh certificates instead of just public keys in my organisation. My goal is to keep uid the same for each user across the infrastructure and I think the best way to achieve that is to add uid as a certificate attribute (ssh certificates allow that). In my opinion it brings the following benefits:

- there's no need to sync local users db with remote database, so I can spin up a virtual machine and not to wait for my user to appear in the vm;
- it's more reliable as I don't need to keep a remote users db always up and ready for sync;
- should be easier to maintain as I don't need to configure NSS and use custom sync plugins;

I wonder is there any way to extract the attribute and use it in sshd for user login? Is there any way to create user runtime when sshd checks its certificate?

Comment: Most central account databases (LDAP, NIS, Hesiod) are _not_ sync-based, they use direct server lookup with local cache. So there's no wait involved, new accounts show up immediately.

Comment: In this case you highly rely on network and LDAP reliability and can't use the whole power PKI gives you.